# Seaborn Heatmap with logarithmic-scale colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

Is there a way to set the color bar scale to log on a seaborn heat map graph?

I am using a pivot table output from pandas as an input to the call

```py
sns.heatmap(df_pivot_mirror, annot=False, xticklabels=256, yticklabels=128, cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r)
```

Answer (score 58):

If you have a current install of seaborn, `norm=LogNorm()` in the call to `heatmap` works now. (Pointed out in the comments -- thank you.) Adding this to one of the seaborn examples:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme(style='white')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm, Normalize
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")


f3, ax5 = plt.subplots(1,1)
sns.heatmap(flights, square=True, norm=LogNorm())
```

[image: Heatmap with lognorm colorbar, four tick labels]

You can pass through colorbar arguments as keywords in the `seaborn` wrapper, but they sometimes collide with the seaborn choices:

```py
sns.heatmap(flights, square=True, norm=LogNorm(), cbar_kws={'ticks':MaxNLocator(2), 'format':'%.e'})
```

[image: Heatmap with lognorm colorbar, four tick labels with inconsistent numerical formatting]

For comparison, this is the `matplotlib` heatmap without seaborn's improvements -- the colorbar arguments have both been applied:

```py
f5, ax6 = plt.subplots(1,1)
im6 = plt.imshow(flights, norm=LogNorm())
cbar6 = ax.figure.colorbar(im6, ax=ax6, ticks=MaxNLocator(2), format='%.e')
```

[image: Heatmap with lognorm colorbar, two tick labels, scientific number formatting]

If you have to use an older install and `LogNorm` doesn't work in seaborn, see the previous versions of this answer for a workaround.

Comment: seaborn issue https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/459 also makes it fixable (a different way)

Comment: The only thing is if some of your values are negative, then that's a problem.  Hyperbolic inverse sin (arcsinh) works better for negative and 0 values.

Comment: There isn't an arcsinh built-in to matplotlib, but you can use SymLogNorm for negative values. 
 Not sure if it handles 0's though. 
 https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colormapnorms-py

Comment: Is there a way to enable the logarithmic-color scale in a 2D histogram done by `sns.jointplot`?

Comment: A log scale in [a distplot like this?](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) I think that deserves to be another question.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the issue with the hard-coded tick-locator seems to have been fixed in recent versions of seaborn. The only thing I had to do was to specify `norm=LogNorm()` and that resulted in logarithmic ticks as well.

Comment: You can use `LogNorm(clip=True)` to map 0s to the bottom of the colorscale.

Comment: in case anyone else ends up here looking for sns.histplot, you have to pass `vmin =None` and `vmax = None`, otherwise you get an error.

Answer (score 30):

**Short Answer:**

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

sns.heatmap(df, norm=LogNorm())
```

Answer (score 17):

You can normalize the values on the colorbar with [matplotlib.colors.LogNorm](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LogNorm.html).
I also had to manually set the labels in seaborn and ended up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math

import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

data = np.random.rand(20, 20)

log_norm = LogNorm(vmin=data.min().min(), vmax=data.max().max())
cbar_ticks = [math.pow(10, i) for i in range(math.floor(math.log10(data.min().min())), 1+math.ceil(math.log10(data.max().max())))]

sn.heatmap(
    data,
    norm=log_norm,
    cbar_kws={"ticks": cbar_ticks}
)
```

[image: heatmap rand]

Answer (score 5):

Responding to cphlewis (I don't have enough reputation), I solved this problem using `cbar_kws`; as I saw here: [seaborn clustermap: set colorbar ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076339/seaborn-clustermap-set-colorbar-ticks).

For example `cbar_kws={"ticks":[0,1,10,1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5]}`.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
s=np.random.rand(20,20)
sns.heatmap(s, norm=LogNorm(s.min(),s.max()),
            cbar_kws={"ticks":[0,1,10,1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5]},
            vmin = 0.001, vmax=10000)
plt.show()
```

Have a nice day.